# Apache KeepAlive on API Server

Tags: apache, api, keep-alive

I have a LAMP server (Quad Core Debian with 4GB RAM, Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3) with Rackspace which is used as an API Server.  I would like to know what is the best KeepAlive option for Apache given our setup.

- The API server hosts a single PHP file which responds with plain JSON. This is a fairly hefty file which performs some MySql reads/writes and quite a few Memcache lookups.
- We have about 90 clients that are logged into the system at any one time.
- Roughly 1/3rd of clients would be idle.
- Of the active clients (roughly 60) they send a request to the API every 3 seconds.
- Clients switch from active to idle and vice versa every 15 or 20 minutes or so.

With KeepAlive On, the server goes nuts and memory peaks at close to 4GB (swap is engaged etc). 
With KeepAlive Off, the memory sits at 3GB however I notice that Apache is constantly killing and creating new processes to handle each connection.

So, my three options are:

1. **KeepAlive On and KeepAliveTimeout Default** - In this case I guess I will just need to get more RAM.
2. **KeepAlive On and KeepAliveTimeout Low (perhaps 10 seconds?)** If KeepAliveTimeout is set at 10 seconds, will a client maintain a constant connection to that one process by accessing the resource at regular 3 second intervals? When that client becomes idle for longer than 10 seconds will the process then be killed? If so I guess option 2 looks like the best one to go for?
3. **KeepAlive Off** This is clearly best for RAM, but will it have an impact on the response times due to the work involved in setting up a new process for each request?

Which option is best?

Comment: have you considered apache threaded + running php in fastcgi at all?

Comment: I have looked into this. As I understand it, with a threaded MPM, one error can impact on all clients under the same process. I do think this is the best option (unless we start buying more servers/ram) but will need to do a lot more research before we make a big switch like that! Thanks for the comment

Comment: One other thing -- running an opcache? One of two things will happen: you'll use more RAM and make no real performance gain in the processing of your PHP script, or you'll save a decent bit of processing because your server will not have to do so much work to parse thePHP script.  (the cost/benefit will entirely depend on the script itself that's being run -- in most cases, it helps)

Comment: ...okay I lied, thought of something you may want to keep an eye on.  https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php  once it's stable with PHP 5.3, this may save you a lot of server load.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Instead of managing the `KeepAlive` settings, which clearly have no real advantage in your particular situation between the 3 options, you should consider switching the Apache to an event or a thread based MPM where you could easily use `KeepAlive On` and set the `Timeout` value high.

I would go as far as also considering the switch to Apache on Windows. The benefit here is that it's MPM is completely thread based and takes advantage of Windows preference for threads over processes. You can easily do 512 threads with KeepAlive On and Timeout of 3-10 seconds on 1-2GB of RAM.

[WampDeveloper Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) -
[Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) -
[WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Otherwise, your only other options are to switch MPM from Prefork to Worker...
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html

Or to Event (which also got better with Apache 2.4)...
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/event.html

Comment: as a note, it's not recommended to run XAMPP in a production environment -- not even by the XAMPP developers.  Also, the latest releases of XAMPP are known to be extremely buggy; the latest release that's actually stable, I found, was 1.7.3 when I was hunting for something usable a month or so ago.

Comment: Thanks for feedback! As I mentioned above, a threaded MPM is definitely an option, and given the feedback here seems like I should research it some more. Switching to windows would mean re-writing a lot of other daemons that run on the server. Would the benefits be that great compared to sticking with Linux? 

I'll mark this as answered because it is the proper solution to my question. I guess the apache tweaking could nearly be a separate one (for short term improvements)

Comment: Niall, one of the things about Windows that people don't know, is that Apache+PHP+MySQL are bigger here than they are on Linux (more downloads for the win32 binaries are reported from mysql.org since 2009, etc) and the entire set up is rock solid. And the thread-based model is much more efficient here. Not really sure what benefits you'll see (aside from that) except for now being forced to having OS-independent daemons (from a rewrite - might as well make them work on both OSs) OR perhaps being forced to Virtualize your hardware (to run both Windows and Linux)... AKA future benefits.

Comment: I don't know anything about how WIndows performs nowadays (It used to be awful under a LAMP environment), but the threaded MPM is most certainly a good answer.

Comment: Just want to remark on the fallacy about Windows platform being more popular for PHP, so people are not mislead.  Think about it. If you run Linux, and you get PHP or MySQL installed, where does it come from?  Probably your Linux repository, not mysql.org or php home page.  Windows users are certainly not going to find it on their Windows DVD nor download it from Microsoft.  Therefore the Windows platform count on many open source packages will be artificially high because they don't count who downloaded it from Debian, CentOS, Ubuntu, Redhat, etc.  Please compare apples to apples.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your php script is leaking memory. Before making them long running processes you should get to grips with that.

If you have not a good idea of the memory usage per request and from request to request adding memory is not a real solution. It might help for now and break again next week.

I would keep running separate processes till memory management is under control. If you have response problems currently your best bet is add another server to spread load.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have the PHP streamlined as much as possible, checked by some PHP experts and it's not leaking any memory. The memory usage per request is about 20M RES and 250M VIRT. I'm looking into disabling some apache modules to lower apache footprint. There is also a lot of logging too on all requests, a large DB server and a few other processes on the box too. So that might explain why it looks like a lot of memory is consumed. If I switch Apache off close to 1.5GB is in use anyhow. I guess it's a case of tweaking some apache setting, KeepAlive and MaxClients etc

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you should be checking is whether the clients are actually using the keepalive functioality at all. I'm not sure what you mean by an 'API server' but if its some sort of webservice then (IME) its rather difficult to implement well behaved clients using keepalives.(See %k directive for mod_log_config).

ALso, we really need to know what your objectives and constraints are? Performance / capacity / low cost?

Is this running over HTTP or HTTPS - there's a big difference in latency.

I'd have said that a keeplive time of 10 seconds is ridiculously high - not low at all.

Even if you've got 90 clients holding connections open, 4Gb seems a rather large amount of memory for them to be using - I'e run systems with 150-200 concurrent connections to complex PHP scripts using approx 0.5Gb over resting usage. Your figures of 250 + 90 x 20M only gives you a footprint of about 2Gb (I know is not that simple - but its not much more complicated).

For the figures you've given I wouldn't expect any benefit - but a significantly bigger memory footprint - using anything over 5 seconds for the keepalive. You could probably use a keepalive time of 2 seconds without any significant loss of throughput, But there's no substitute for measuring the effectiveness of various configs - and analysing the data to find the optimal config.

Certainly if you find that your clients are able to take advantage of keepalives and get a measurable benefit from doing so then you need to find the best way of accomodating that. Using a threaded server might help a little with memory usage, but you'll probably find a lot more benefit in running a reverse proxy in front of the webserver - particularly which SSL.

Besides that you may get significant benefits through normal tuning - code profiling, output compression etc.

Comment: It's just a web service running on a server.  

You are spot on with the memory footprint, it is roughly 2GB in total (1.5GB RAM in use on server in other areas).

I suggested 10 seconds for the following reason: If the client connects every 3 seconds and the apache process stays alive for 10 seconds, would the same process not remain with the client until they stop making requests (ie: Pretty much working like a persistent connection)? 

Short term, tweaking Apache is our only option really. Long term, threaded MPM, nginx, 
json-rpc are all things I'll look at